# Nexus 5 takes forever and a day to charge

Tags: charging, nexus-5, kernel

Since I have installed franco Kernel on my device, charging takes longer than normal  (I'd guess 4-5 hours?). But today charging became extremely slow. I plugged it in overnight and this morning it was at 87%.

[image: click to enlarge]

In the screenshot you can see that it was on for ~ 1d 20h, and ~ 1d 10h it was on battery. That means it needed ~ 10h to get from 4% to 87%. Is this a common problem with the franco Kernel?

PS: I plugged it into the wall, not USB.

Comment: Looks like your cell reception is pretty bad, that might contribute to slowing your charging time. Are you using the original plug and cable?

Comment: It could be the cable, using a PC to charge, a dodgy custom kernel, rogue applications/processes using a lot of power, the bad cell reception you seem to have. It's very hard to tell with the information given. I'd try another ROM AND Kernel and see if this persists.

Comment: I am using the original plug and an amazon basics cable. This may be the cause. Wireless charging gives me ~550mA.

Comment: try charging with your phone off, to isolate the problem. If it is a software/power usage problem then it will charge faster, if its the cable or charger itself then it will charge at the same speed.